# Let js look for the thing that was shown?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, steam

in the json file i have this

```
{
"Class Token - Scout": {
    "defindex": [5003],
    "prices": {
        "3": {
            "Tradable": {
                "Craftable": [{
                    "value": 244,
                    "currency": "keys",
                    "difference": 266,
                    "last_update": 1339261330
                }]
            }
        },
        "6": {
            "Tradable": {
                "Craftable": [{
                    "value": 0.16,
                    "currency": "metal",
                    "difference": 0.05,
                    "last_update": 1341200357
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the code i have is

```
//The price of an item
const price = require('./price.json')

//Things i have
var item = 'Class Token - Scout'


if(item == price){
    console.log(price.defindex)
    console.log(price.prices.6.Tradable.Craftable.value)
}
```

i want it to search in the price.json file if the item name was there, if it was return the defindex of the item and the value

Comment: item is a string, price is an object, they will never be `==`

Comment: so what should i do, im new to js and couldnt figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an important step:

```js
//The price of an item
const price = require('./price.json')

//Things i have
var item = 'Class Token - Scout'


const itemPrice = price[item];

if (itemPrice){
    console.log(itemPrice.defindex)
    console.log(itemPrice.prices['6'].Tradable.Craftable.value)
}
```